# Windows server 2012R2 Classic ASP Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e4d'

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp-classic, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a classic ASP application which has been moved to windows server 2012R2 two days before and sice then its showing a connection error in some sections of the application.

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e4d' Login failed for user 'sa'.

Login and some listing functionality are working fine but when Im accessing a billing page its showing the above mentioned error and we are using the same DB connection in the billing page also.

Following is the connection string used

```
Dim datasource,cnnCompanyDbase
Set cnnCompanyDbase=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnnCompanyDbase.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Initial Catalog=CompanyDatabase;Data Source=192.168.0.20;User Id=sa; Password=satest;"
```

Previously the application was running fine on windows server 2003.

**Edit**
After going through the code in detail, I found there is some slight difference in the record set opening with the DB command object.

Following is the two scenario

**Working Condition**

```
qryStaff="SELECT * FROM [Staff]"

Set rstStaff=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rstStaff.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rstStaff.Open qryStaff,cnnCompanyDbase
```

**Error condition**

```
qryJobClients = "SELECT Client FROM Jobs WHERE Jobs.[Job-billing]=3"
Set rstJobClients=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rstJobClients.CursorType = adOpenStatic 
rstJobClients.Open qryJobClients,getDBConnect()
```

In the above case the method getDBConnect() returns the cnnCompanyDbase. I have printed both and getting the exact value, only the difference is one is from a method and another is directly given DB command.

Comment: It's very bad practice to use your super user account for a connection string.  Create an account specifically for the application, limit access to the database(s) used by that app alon, and use that instead.

Comment: Yes im using it as another account, I have given it as sample connection

Comment: You're confident that both connection strings are identical?

Comment: This is what we use for Classic ASP apps to SQL Server 2012: `PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=<datasource>;UID=<uid>;PWD=<pwd>;DATABASE=<database>;`

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your connection string, but you could try a native client one.  Here are the details for Sql Server 2005. http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-9-0-oledb-provider/

Comment: After digging a lot, it seems there is some thing wrong with the opening of record set, I will update my post with the code difference